# Ergonomically running escript codepath from source

Tags: elixir, command-line-interface

I'm writing a CLI app in elixir with escript. Running it is a two step process from source:

```sh
mix escript.build
./my-cli
```

This is a bit annoying in the middle of development and I'd much rather use a single call. However, `mix run` ties in to OTP, which I'm not using. Similarly, just calling `lib/cli.ex` will not run the specified escript entrypoint, but rather compile the module and run whatever's in the top level.

In python, the solution would be

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

def main(*argv):
  print(argv)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main(sys.argv[1:])
```

if the built CLI uses the `main` function as entrypoint with CLI arguments used in argv.

Replicating this in elixir would be relatively easy:

```
#! /usr/bin/env elixir

defmodule MyCLI do
  def main(args) do
    IO.inspect(args)
  end
end

MyCLI.main(System.argv())
```

However, this will call the script as part of the `escript.build` process. It can be mitigated by adding a clause to the `main` function:

```
def main(["escript.build" | _]) do
end
```

but this still doesn't catch e.g. `mix compile` and would thus require *another* empty clause, not to mention it could theoretically break in usage if the user provides a first argument such as `compile`. Additionally, it limits project namespace and will not provide access to e.g. the `MixProject`, which begs the question if this python-ism is a dead end. How do I best do this?

Comment: I guess I'm missing something here.  Why don't you just use `escript my-cli`?  I mean do you need to rebuild the escript every time?

Comment: If I'm in the middle of working on the project, yes, since the escript is a compiled binary that would have to be re-compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't just combine the two steps?

```
mix escript.build && ./my-cli
```

Then hit up + enter each time to build & run? Or create a simple shell script called something simple like "run", if you don't want to rely on your shell history?